# Derivative of a determinant with differentiable functions as elements

Tags: derivatives, determinant

Let $f_{ij}(t)$ be a differentiable function, 
$$F(t)=\begin{vmatrix}
f_{11}(t)&f_{12}(t)&\dots&f_{1n}(t)\\
f_{21}(t)&f_{22}(t)&\dots&f_{2n}(t)\\
\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
f_{n1}(t)&f_{n2}(t)&\dots&f_{nn}(t)\\
\end{vmatrix},$$

Prove that $\frac d{dt}F(t)=\sum_{j=1}^n F_j(t)$, where

$$F_j(t)=\begin{vmatrix}
f_{11}(t)&f_{12}(t)&\dots&\frac d{dt}f_{1j}(t)&\dots&f_{1n}(t)\\
f_{21}(t)&f_{22}(t)&\dots&\frac d{dt}f_{2j}(t)&\dots&f_{2n}(t)\\
\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots&&\vdots\\
f_{n1}(t)&f_{n2}(t)&\dots&\frac d{dt}f_{nj}(t)&\dots&f_{nn}(t)\\
\end{vmatrix},$$

I’ve just learnt determinants as my first chapter in linear algebra and stumbled upon this question.

I think it have something to do with the expansion of the determinant as 
$$\sum_{(k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n)} (-1)^{N(k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n)} a_{1k_1}a_{2k_2}\dots a_{nk_n}$$

but I’m really not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

It would be very helpful if you start with a two by two determinant and use product rule of differentiation  to see the result.
Then you can easily generalize to higher dimension.

Comment: Thanks, I’m currently trying to prove by induction. I think I have an idea for the generalization!

Comment: Thanks for your attention.